# Difficult "select" expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have a project model which has multiple "open tasks":

```
[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<Task> OpenTasks
{
   get
   {
       //All tasks where status id == 1 (= open tasks)
       return Tasks.Where(t => t.TaskStatusId == (int)EnumTaskStatus.taskStatus.openTask);
   }
}
```

A task model has multiple users:

```
public virtual ICollection<Useraccount> Useraccounts { get; set; }
```

Now I would like to get all open tasks of a specific user of a project.
It would look like this:

```
project.OpenTasks.Where(my user is in t => T.useraccounts);
```

But I'm not sure how my where condition would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
project.OpenTasks.Where(x => x.Useraccounts.Contains(myUser));
```

If `Useraccount` doesn't override the equality members, you need to use something like this:

```
project.OpenTasks.Where(x => x.Useraccounts.Any(x => x.Id == myUser.Id));
```

Comment: @mosquito87 `project.OpenTasks.FindIndex(myUser)` is better ? Rather then inner loop ?

Comment: @PankajGarg: That doesn't really make sense. OpenTasks returns tasks, myUser is a user. They don't mix like this.

Comment: Consider a situation, when you have 100 Task...Each task may have it's unique/duplicate userid. right? Now see the above line of code in your post. This says for each 100 task iteration, it will check for each user record, despite of the fact that there is any match or not. right ? That's the magic of `Contains`.

Comment: @PankajGarg: Your comments make *no sense at all*. (1) `FindIndex` is a member of `List<T>`. `OpenTasks` is an `IEnumerable<Task>` not a `List<Task>`. (2). Even if `OpenTasks` would be of type `List<Task>`, `FindIndex` would require an `Task` instance. But you want to pass a `Useraccount`.